# ASP.NET Core: Error when using a custom DbContext while also using Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've created a dbContext based on an existing Azure SQL Database using Entity Framework. I added this database to my app's services as follows:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Identity Database Context
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataDb"),
            optionsBuilders =>
            optionsBuilders.MigrationsAssembly("WebPortal"))
        );

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //Custom Database Context
        services.AddDbContext<CustomDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomDb"))
        );

        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

When I try to run this I get the following error message:

> InvalidOperationException: The DbContextOptions passed to the IdentityDbContext constructor must be a DbContextOptions. When registering multiple DbContext types make sure that the constructor for each context type has a DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic DbContextOptions parameter.

The constructor for my custom Context does have a  parameter:

```
    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Try this public IdentityDbContext (DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext > options)
   : base(options)
{
}

Comment: @nemke Where should I add that?

Comment: Maybe a `CustomDbContext` should use `DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext>` instead of `DbContextOptions<WITSPeopleContext>`?

Comment: Can you show `CustomDbContext`?

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad my mistake, it is using DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext>, I've updated the question

Comment: Hi what is the solution ?

Comment: @hsbsid did you solve this I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
my scenario was that, i needed two Context **ReadDataContext** and **WriteDataContext**,i solved that exception with bottom Contexts

```
public class ReadOnlyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public ReadOnlyDataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = typeof(TaskConfiguration).Assembly;
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);
    }
}
```

> Pay attention to the **DataContext** Constructor

```
 public class WriteDataContext : DbContext, IContext
{
    public WriteDataContext(DbContextOptions<WriteDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = typeof(TaskConfiguration).Assembly;
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);
    }
}
```

> And for registeration

```
 services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection"));
            opt.LogTo(Console.WriteLine).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
 services.AddDbContext<ReadOnlyDataContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection"));
            opt.LogTo(Console.WriteLine).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
```

Comment: Similar situation for me.  I had two DbContexts and it was pulling the options from the other one.  Changing the default "DbContextOptions" to a generic (more specific) parameter in the constructor solved my problem:  DbContextOptions<ApplicationAuditDbContext>